# reledmac two-column footnote with xltabular

Tags: footnotes, two-column, reledmac, xltabular

EDITED: Can someone help set up reledmac two-column footnote with xltabular? I find that the hyperref of footnotes in the xltabular environment directs to the wrong place. Any help is much appreciated.

N.B: I had some inaccurate footnotemarks in my previous MWE, which I have now corrected.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nocritical,
    noend,
     series={A}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\def\thempfootnote{{\itshape\@alph\c@mpfootnote}} 
\arrangementX[A]{twocol}
\colalignX{\relax } 
\beforenotesX{2em plus 1.5em minus 1.5em} 
  
\usepackage[verbose=silent]{microtype}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue}
}    

\begin{document}
This is a test sentence\footnoteA{test main footnote}

\addtocounter{footnoteA}{1}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lX p{.5\textwidth}}
a & b\footnoteAmark[2]\\
c & d\footnoteAmark[3]\\
\end{xltabular}
\footnoteAtext[2]{first xltabular footnote}
\footnoteAtext[3]{second xltabular footnote}

This is a second test sentence\footnoteA{test second main footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where was a bug indeed in reledmac. Exceptionnaly, I had time.

So the version 2.39.5 of reledmac, just sent on CTAN, solves it. The previous version 2.39.4, solved it only partially.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you so much. Everything works A-Okay now!